# Routing IN RUBY on RAILS

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So for example, if I give like this

```
map.root :controller => "pages", :action => 'show', :slug => "**homepage**" 
map.connect '*slug', :controller => 'pages', :action => 'show'
```

what will happen?

Comment: May be you will tell us what you **want** to do with that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you run either `rake routes` or read [the routing guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html)? Perhaps these will aid you.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can deduce from your statement, map.root will just set the url root, "http://www.abc.com/", to automatically redirect to the "pages" controller and execute the "show" method and the slug is a human-readable id for that root.

From best I can tell, I am still a bit of a n00b in Rails, the connect statement will assign the pages controller and show action to all urls that end in "slug" within the root.  For example, "http://www.abc.com/firstslug" would route to "/pages/show".